# Highlighting the first 5 days of a month using conditional formatting

Tags: excel, date, formatting, conditional-statements, highlighting

I have an excel sheet which automatically updates the new dates every day. when it reaches the 1st-5th of the month, I want it to be highlighted.

However, I'm having difficulty in making it work. Tried using the =DAY function but can't seem to get it to highlight in the conditional formatting section of excel.

Anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: How is your data setup?

Comment: What formula did you try?

Comment: like for A1 `=DAY(A1)<=5` or for X23 `=DAY(X23)<=5`???

Comment: Yes we know how to do it, but some example date to see how things are layed out will help with the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your dates are layed out as follows:

[image]

<sub>Note the numbers are still full excel dates, the cells are custom formatted to display only the day number.  This formatting has no barring on your formulas.</sub>

The important thing to note is I have selected the area I want the conditional formatting to apply with the active cell in the upper left corner.  That last part is key.

Now we can go to conditional formatting and apply the formula Dirk Reichel suggested, but only for the active cell.  It will update the cell references as it moves through the range.  So in conditional formatting we select by formula and use:

[image: conditional formatting]

```
=day(AH18)<=5
```

Adjust AH18 to suit the top left of your data range.  Then we choose some colouring, font changes etc.

Proof of concept

[image: Proof of concept]

and with an updated and changed first date:

[image: Proof of concept 2]